# Book for linear systems equation

Tags: linear-algebra

What is qood practical book for linear systems equation ? for solving the method to explained the method cholesky and lu factorization

thanks

Comment: Introduction to Linear Algebra by Strang Gilbert.

Answer (score 0):

i found the book is to easy to understand are the book

Matrix Computations 4th editions 
Golub, G.H. and Van Loan, C.F.